# JSON associative array to Dart/Flutter object

Tags: json, dart, flutter

I have JSON response with the following object structure:

```
{
"cities": {
    "5": {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "New York"
    },
    "6": {
        "id": "6",
        "name": "Los Angeles"
    }
},
"total": 2,
"page": 1,
"total_pages": 1
}
```

As you can see, "cities" is clearly an associative type array that is listing all the cities being referenced. I'm trying to create a Dart object that can hold these cities values from a JSON object.
The city object is pretty straightforward:

```
class City {
  int id;
  String name;
  City(this.id, this.name);
  City.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
  }
}
```

however, I'm not sure how to create the CityResults object. I usually create a List object from json arrays but I'm not sure how this would work?

Comment: I mean, it is just JSON, so realistically, make something serializable.

Comment: I would recommend using built_value libraries. It is easy and powerful. https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/built_value

Answer (score 2):

You have to fix your `City` class, because your 'id' from json is String, so you have two options:

1- Replace int by String

```
class City {
 String id;
```

or

2- Change the `fromJson` method

```
City.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = int.parse(json['id']);
    name = json['name'];
  }
```

Finally, this could be your parse method :

```
         final Map cityResponse = json.decode(data)["cities"];
            final List<City> cities = cityResponse.values
                .map((jsonValue) => City.fromJson(jsonValue))
                .toList();

            //now you have the list of your cities inside cities variable.    
            cities.forEach((city) => print("City: ${city.id} , ${city.name}"));
```